# How to set sizes for forms to cope with differences in display resolutions?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, screen-resolution

I am designing a .NET app based on an old VB6 app.

The forms in the VB6 app are of a size that would suit older displays with lower resolutions.  Nowadays they only take about third of the height of the screen, when before they might have almost filled the screen up.

What should be the approach to handle this issue?  Do you simply have to make sure your forms fit it into the lowest resolution displays you are likely to support?

Does WPF offer some sort of advantage over Winforms in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Screen.Bounds` to geht the width and height of the users Screen. Use this values on your form create / load to set a desired size.

Check [this site for more information about Screen Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The following is meant as *general* advice, which will have exceptions...

You should not design fixed size forms, except for dialogs, and dialogs will often need to be sized exactly to fit their input, while obviously assuring they don't overflow any reasonable screen size.

So basically, it should not matter what size users' screens are.

and yes; WPF (and winforms, for that matter) has controls which can help you layout a flexible form.

Comment: What would be the point of having a resizable form? If the user makes it bigger, wouldn't they just create more empty space in the form?

Comment: @CraigJ The point of resizable forms is to avoid this question, entirely. Let the user decide how big they want the form. Look at how applications work: Visual Studio, Sql Server Management Studio; Office Word; Firefox; Windows Control Panel; Microsoft Management Console... they all use sizable forms for everything except dialogs. Empty space? So what?

Comment: @CraigJ I should also further note that many of those programs even allow their dialogs to be resized. That's even better.